# How can I display my logo on my DokuWiki's title?

Tags: image, dokuwiki

I have a DokuWiki and I'd like to place a logo on the title bar at the top of the page? How can I do this? Note that I am not referring to the title bar at the top of the browser, but rather the title bar on the website itself.

I tried inserting the DokuWiki syntax: {{public:logo.jpg?100x100}}, but this simply rendered as plain text and not an image.

Is it possible to put an image in the page title?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's no config option for this, you'd have to hack it in `\dokuwiki-2009-02-14\lib\tpl\index.php` I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, a better solution would be to build a plugin or a template but I'm not sure how those work with dokuwiki (something on my todo list). I've got a feeling plugins only affect page content but templates might help you.

Comment: `./lib/tpl/index.php` is **completely wrong**! You won't be able to change the logo or anything else in that file as it is not used for the template or anything you can see on your wiki. (It's only there to show your active template's colour settings.)

Comment: Maybe there was no config option back in 2009, but in later versions of Dokuwiki there is a possibility to config the logo easily, as this other answer in this threat explains: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12901769/3495761

Answer (score 38):

Easy: Rename your logo as `logo.png` and place it into :wiki namespace. It will show automatically.

This solution works on template "[dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/template:dokuwiki)" (default one on dokuwiki old stable version "[Adora Belle](https://www.dokuwiki.org/changes#release_2012-10-13_adora_belle)" and in current one "[Weatherwax](https://www.dokuwiki.org/changes#release_2013-05-10_weatherwax)"):

**Deeper:**

We can look at the `tpl_header.php` file, lines 21&23:

```php
    // get logo either out of the template images folder or data/media folder
...
    $logo = tpl_getMediaFile(array(':wiki:logo.png', 'images/logo.png'), false, $logoSize);
```

Ok: `tpl_getMediaFile()` will look for a file `logo.png` in the media namespace called `wiki`.

So I go to dokuwiki File Manager and I upload my `logo.png` file in the `wiki` namespace. I refresh the page and smile.

[image: solution with dokuwiki File Manager]

Hope That Helps

Answer (score 3):

In modern versions of `DokuWiki` you don't have to make your own template. Simply upload a file called `logo.png` to the `wiki` or root namespace in the `DokuWiki Media Manager`.

This is the line of template code that gets the logo:
https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/master/lib/tpl/dokuwiki/tpl_header.php#L23

You can tell that it is first checking   `logo.png` in the `wiki` namespace with `:wiki:logo.png` and then `logo.png` in the root namespace with `:logo.png`.

If it doesn't find either, it falls back on `images/logo.png`, which is the default logo.

Comment: Just to note that this is apparently a functionality of the default template, not the DokuWiki itself. Hence it will most probably not work with other templates.

Answer (score 1):

(for latest versions of Dokuwiki)

You should create your own template, and do whatever hack you need to do.

It is located in lib/tpl/

Just copy the default directory with your own name (this will be available in the admin area later), something like "company", and edit:

```
  <div class="pagename">
    <img src="<?php echo DOKU_TPL; ?>images/logo.png" align="absmiddle"/>
    [[<?php tpl_link(wl($ID,'do=backlink'),tpl_pagetitle($ID,true),'title="'.$lang['btn_backlink'].'"')?>]]
  </div>
```

You can build the HTML as you like... but the example above works just fine (the image is located in the lib/tpl/company/images/)

You can then change the template of your Wiki by updating the configuration at:
Admin > configuration manager > template